# StoryBoard failed - from xcode 8.3.3 to xcode9 beta2

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xcode9-beta

After move my project from 8.3.3 to 9.0 beta2, the storyboard counld not work, it just show the outline of the orignal, and i cant complie it, shows the error below.
Anyone knows why?

[image: Storyborad only show the outline]

[image: Error info]

Comment: Clean the project (`⌘`+`⇧`+`K`), quit Xcode and then re-open the project. This might help.

Comment: i have tryed it dozen of time, it woulnt work, dam, i decide to go back to 8.3.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these steps to solve your problem:

1. Open your project in Xcode (any 9.0 or 8.3.3)
2. Right 'Click' on story board.
3. Select 'Open As' >> 'Source Code'
4. find keyword 'minToolsVersion' (it may be more than one time) under 'dependencies'. (Look at below images)
5. Update value for minToolsVersion to 8.3 or 9.0 (if you don't want to work anymore with Xode 8.x, then set 9.0 here)
6. Save
7. Again, Right 'Click' on story board.
8. Select 'Open As' >> 'Interface Builder - Storyboard'
9. Now, Xcode Menus >> 'Editor' >> 'Canvas'
10. **Remove tickmarks** for 'Show Layout Rectanges', 'Show Bounds Rectangles', 'Show Placeholder Rectangles'.

Now you can open your storyboard in Xcode 8.x also.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have used this answer to migrate my storybord from xcode 9 to xcode 8.
by simply changing the value for "documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="9.0" to 8.0.